# Joins vs associations in EF and Linq, performance diff?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I recently removed 3 joins from a linq query against several Entities and used associations between the tables instead.

It seems that the queries now take longer to execute.
I made the changes hoping for some performance improvements.

Is this consistent with what others have observed?
Is there a logical reason for this?
Is there a good rule of thumb about which strategy to use?

Linq query with joins:

```
from n in db.Names  
            .Where(n.ID = "myID")

            **join d in db.InstitutionDemographics on n.ID equals d.ID
            join m in db.MemberAdhocIds on n.ID equals m.ID
            join ba in db.NameAddresses on n.BillingAddressNumber equals ba.AddressNumber
            join sa in db.NameAddresses on n.ShippingAddressNumber equals sa.AddressNumber
            join ma in db.NameAddresses on n.MailingAddressNumber equals ma.AddressNumber
            join mas in db.MemberAdhocServices on n.ID equals mas.InstitutionID**

            join pn in db.PrimaryContactNames on n.ID equals pn.ID into PrimeName
            from pn in PrimeName.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join cd in currentDuesResults on n.ID equals cd.ID into DuesJoin
            from cd in DuesJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join bd in billingDateResults on n.ID equals bd.ID
            into BillingDate
            from bd in BillingDate.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

The ** marked section is what was replaced with associations in the EDMX file. The relationships are 1 to1 and constraints are based on the IDs just like the joins.

I have to also mention that there are no FK relationships on the SQL tables. (legacy stuff that I can not change)

** New information
I've captured the SQL generated by the query using join -vs- associations and run it from SSMS. The performance is almost identical. So it appears that the sql generated is not the issue but something else in how the linq code is working.

Comment: Depends on your associations and your query, but this is not typically the case.  Can you post some code? And how much longer is it taking?

Comment: I'm not sure what code I could post for the association version. It seems to be taking on the order of twice as long to execute. My next step is going to be grabbing the actual SQL queries that the linq produces and see what the differences are.

Comment: You can try posting the relevant portions of your code that show what the associations look like.  And you can post the query itself (before and after the associations were used).

Comment: Most likely you are running into the [N+1 problem](https://www.google.com/search?q=N%2B1+problem).

Comment: Possibly inner joins turned into outer joins. Can you confirm that by monitoring the SQL statements?

Comment: I'm finding that the actual query runs the same either way. There seems to be some difference in the results and how they are handled.